# Print string in maxlines 3 and width parametar, I'm not understand all, can someone help me

Tags: java, class

We are currently working on displaying calendar events to our users in a week view and month view. 
A calendar event may be something like "9:00 John Doe until 10 30 at Office". 
Unfortunately we only have limited screen space to display information about each event. 
We can only display a few lines with a limited maximm number of characters. 
Please write a class with a method that takes the summary string and breaks it down into a maximum number of lines (maxLines Parameter) and 
maximum number of characters per line (width parameter). All lines except the first line should be indented (they should start with a space character), 
but the second character in an indented line should not be another space (so that second space must not be included).

Example (text = "9:00 John Doe until 10 30 at Office", width=7, maxLines = 3): 
9:00 Jo
 hn Doe
 until

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. You're probably getting downvoted due to the lack of any evidence you've tried to solve your own problem. :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down for info on why people downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package com.TnationChallange;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    for (String part : getParts("limited screen space to display information", 7, 3)) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}

private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize, int maxLine) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
        parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
        maxLine++;
        if (maxLine == 3) {
            break;
        }

    }
    return parts;
}
```

}